# Error when connecting mylyn Gitlab connector to Eclipse

Tags: gitlab, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to configure the Mylyn Gitlab Connector for Eclipse Oxygen v4.7.1a but when I try to add a new task it throws me an exception and it does not let me continue with the creation of the new task.

Enter correctly my data and the url address of the gitlab repository and even probe with several url and with all of them throw me the same exception.

[image]

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:980)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.wizards.NewTaskWizard.performFinish(NewTaskWizard.java:113)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.wizards.SelectRepositoryPage.performFinish(SelectRepositoryPage.java:295)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.wizards.MultiRepositoryAwareWizard.performFinish(MultiRepositoryAwareWizard.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.TasksUiUtil.openNewTaskEditor(TasksUiUtil.java:237)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.TasksUiUtil.openNewTaskEditor(TasksUiUtil.java:253)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.actions.NewTaskAction.run(NewTaskAction.java:95)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.actions.NewTaskAction.run(NewTaskAction.java:102)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.exceptions.GitlabException: Invalid path in host
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.GitlabTaskDataHandler.getAttributeMapper(GitlabTaskDataHandler.java:67)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.util.TasksUiInternal.createTaskData(TasksUiInternal.java:872)
at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.wizards.NewTaskWizard$1.run(NewTaskWizard.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.exceptions.GitlabException: Invalid path in host
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.exceptions.GitlabExceptionHandler.handle(GitlabExceptionHandler.java:20)
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.ConnectionManager.validate(ConnectionManager.java:139)
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.ConnectionManager.get(ConnectionManager.java:159)
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.ConnectionManager.get(ConnectionManager.java:45)
at de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core.GitlabTaskDataHandler.getAttributeMapper(GitlabTaskDataHandler.java:65)
... 3 more
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you find a solution, please post an answer. I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: update mylyn connector but it still does not work, I get this error:

Error creating new task
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.


I think I'll have to go back to the version of Ubuntu 16.04 there works correctly

Comment: Could you post the git url you are using ?

Comment: try with several url of my repository in gitlab and with all of them throw me the same error

Comment: this is the url  https://gitlab.com/Navastud/wdsur  with which I am testing

Comment: and what you put in 'label' field ? this is my url: https://git.company/somegroup/project.git

Comment: no, I put it in the 'server' field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161226/discussion-between-nelson-teixeira-and-david-navarro-astudillo).

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira   , I had to use the private gitlab token in the additional configuration as indicated by ts.tsogtgerel

Comment: Thanks for the reminder David. It finally worked for me also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right click on Mylyn repository and select Repository -> Properties
2. Expand Additional Settings and check "Use private token"

[image]

works well for me.

```
Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
```

Comment: how to get a gitlab base url?

Comment: I leave it empty

Comment: Finally, a solution. It worked for me also. Thank you :)

Comment: what am I supposed to put on Private token ?